# jQuery grid view with fixed header

Tags: jquery, gridview, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables

I'm working on a project that requires to display 15 column each row.

I'm using jquery datatable with horizontal scroll to achieve this goal which is working fine but there is one issue now i want fixed header with horizontal scroll in jquery datatable which is currently not supportable.

Is there any other grid view like jquery datable which support fixed header with horizontal scrolling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html) first link in google. There is a large variety of solutions...

Comment: currently datatable not supported fixed header with horizontal scroll